# static char arrays & pointers memory

Tags: c++, arrays, static

A C++ program consists of two .cpp files, main.cpp and f.cpp. Code of the main.cpp file is as follows:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(char* s,int n);

const int N=10;
static char s[N];
static char a[N];

int main ()
{
    int i;  
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        a[i]='0'+i;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        cout<<a[i]; 
    cout<<'\n';

    f(s,N);

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        cout<<a[i]; 

    cout<<'\n';
}
```

The function `f` is defined in the file f.cpp. The program compiles without errors & warnings. When executed, the program regularly ends, leaving the following on `cout`:

```
0123456789
!123456789
```

What's your comment on validity and behavior of this program? Explain in detail.

*I suppose the f function is illegally accessing a's memory somehow, maybe because s is right before a in memory, so something with indexes occurs... I'm really not sure, however, because I guess `static` also changes things somehow..*

Comment: Err... and what is the code of `f`?

Comment: So you're supposed to guess what went wrong in the call to `f`? This is homework, right?

Comment: @Tudor well that's the point of the question, to realize what's going on and how could the `f(s, N)` line change the data in `a`

Comment: What does it mean "program regularly ends"? That it runs ok?

Comment: Can't you just use a debugger? What's the point of this guessing game?

Comment: I guess there is a macro `#define s a` passed to the compiler with `-D`.

Comment: Static variables are stored in data section of program, if function f is not doing correct boundary check then it might write over next variable - in this case, a[].

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I don't really know what's -D. However, I guess that this should have something to do with the `static` arrays `a` and `s`? Or would `#define s a ` not work if they weren't `static`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb wouldn't that cause a duplicate definition?

Comment: `f` might look like this: `void f(char* s, int n) { s[n] = '!'; }`. Undefined behavior, but might work in some compilers.

Comment: @Philipp Yeah that's what jumped first to mind, but when I tried it, the program just returned the normal array `a`. I tried even `s[n+1]` and `s[-1]`, still didn't change anything..

Comment: @Philipp Lol, `s[n+2]` gives the correct output :) Maybe there is the '/0' character after or sth, but yeah, the point is good :)

Comment: @Vidak It depends on where the compiler places `a` and `s` in the executable. For example, on my system I have to write `s[-n]` because the compiler swaps `a` and `s`.

Comment: This is not a comment site and we do not do your homework for you. This question should be burned.

Comment: @DeadMG I was just thinking what a good question. We have a poster who is interested in understanding UB. That's a rare thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *depends* on the compiler. With `gcc-4.3.4`, if you can define `f` as:

```
void f(char* s,int n) { s[-n] = '!' ; } //danger!
```

to produce that output which you have posted. Here is online demo : http://ideone.com/8YT7k

But **be warned** that such coding is *really really* bad, and you should not be coding like that, as the actual behavior depends on the compiler, its version, settings, and options.

Whether *static arrays are placed near each other* or not depends on the compiler, and your program shouldn't assume that. In this case, however, they are placed adjacent, but then it seems to depend on the other factors. For example, if I print the address of `s` and `a` at the end of your code, without removing anything from your code, then `s` has higher address than `a`, but if I removed your code, then `a` has higher address than `s`. See yourself:

- http://ideone.com/HTtKn  (`s` has higher address than `a`)
- http://ideone.com/ZVSjk  (`a` has higher address than `s`)

The first one prints:

```
0x804a0df   //address of s
0x804a0d5   //address of a
0xa         //difference of s and a i.e (s-a)
```

but then second one prints this:

```
0x804a0d5   //address of s
0x804a0df   //address of a
0xa         //difference of a and s i.e (a-s) [reversed!]
```

So it depends on the compiler's mood where it places the static arrays!

Comment: Right, and is this even possible in any case if the arrays weren't `static`?

Comment: @Vidak: How would I say that? It is NOT the part of the language, and the compiler can do anything with your code.

Comment: @Vidak: It seems to work in that case too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the code of `f` is:

```
void f(char* arr, int len)
{
    arr[len + 2] = '!';
}
```

It goes past the length of `s` and into the memory where `a` is stored, writing a `!` on the first position. Works on Windows at least.

Comment: yeah, just tried it this second :) And why s[len+2] and not s[len] or s[len+1] ?

Comment: because it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Vidak I suppose the compiler tries to align the arrays on 4-byte words, so there are 2 bytes of padding. To check, try it with N = 12.